# mvc3 modal dialog not displaying

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog

I am having problem displaying the modal dialog in mvc3 project, I found the code below and tried to use it but I am getting an error, I am sure I am missing something I hope someone can help me with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        resizable: false,
        title: 'hi there',
        modal: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            //Load the CreateAlbumPartial action which will return 
            // the partial view _CreateAlbumPartial
            $(this).load("@Url.Action("CreateAlbumPartial")");
        },
        buttons: {
            "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $('#my-button').click(function () {
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

```
public ActionResult CreateAlbumPartial()
{
    return View("_CreateAlbumPartial");
}
```

my error is: "Microsoft jscript runtime error: Object does not support property or method 'dialog' "

I will also appreciate if someone can show me other examples, I want to display a modal dialog in my page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have imported the JQuery scripts, both the .js files and the CSS files right?

Comment: You need to add reference to jquery libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the jQuery AND the jQuery UI libraries?

.dialog is a method provided by jQuery UI, not jQuery.

Comment: I added the JQuery UI library and no more recieve that error, So Thanks!  but after adding     <div id="dialog" title="Create Album" style="overflow: hidden;">
  </div> as part of the html to connect to my dialog box nothing is happening I also added an action in the controller to return a partialview ... Do you have any idea why this might happen.

Comment: well, you also have to link to the css part of the jquery ui library. Have you added that?